# What was the early American church like?

Tags: denomination-survey, church-history

Which denominations were prevalent among the churches of North America in the late 17th century and 18th century?

During that time, was there significant of cooperation or communication between church groups in America and the rest of the world?

When did the first "American denominations" emerge in earnest?

Comment: Um. The title is a very broad question. I like the questions in the body. The first question in the body is good; second question is okay; third question is acceptable. But the title is way too broad.

Comment: The title is meant to be broad. I appreciate your critique of the questions.

Comment: I think this question is far too broad. The late 17th to early 18th century America is, literally, a 100-year timespan, and you're asking about the church in an incredibly religiously diverse, and very large nation. One could write tomes on the topic. Can you make the question more specific somehow?

Comment: Also, consider the fact that there has never been an established church in America or a king who ruled by divine right.

Comment: I think the question is great and answerable. I'll review my historical theology, time permitting, and see what I come up with. As for your last question, the Puritans were the first to emerge in earnest. One of the primary reasons they came over on the Mayflower was religious freedom.

Answer (score 3):

Denominations prevalent in North America in late 17th and 18th centuries:(In approximate order of arrival or apperance) [Note: there may well have been others; these are the ones that come to mind in an overview.]

Roman Catholics, principally in Canada, the far North of New England, and the colony of Maryland;

Anglicans, both the Puritan subset, in Boston, and more mainline flavors in other Southern colonies (e.g. Virginia);

Baptists (originated in Rhode Island under Roger Williams);

Lutherans, first in New Sweden / Delaware, and Pennsylvania, and to a lesser extent in other places.

Dutch Calvinists, in New Amsterdam (under the Reformed denominations) and Scots Calvinists (who eventually became the Presbyterian denominations)

Quakers, in Pennsylvania

Methodists, in Georgia, and other colonies.

Moravians and Mennonites / Amish came to Pennsylvania and North Carolina during the 18th Century.

The most significant communication and co-operation between Christians in the New World and in the Old would likely have been among the Roman Catholics, and the Anglicans.

The first "American denomination" was the Baptists, and the Congregationalists, who evolved form the Puritan Anglicans in New England.

Comment: There were also the "churches of Christ" which came over from Scottland, which were baptistic and originally fellowshiped the Baptists. But in the early 1800s many Baptists became disillusioned with the strict credalism of the various Baptist Associations and broke off either to become Independent Baptists, or to join the churches of Christ, or the Christian Church, which became increasingly separate from the Baptists beginning around 1831. The Christadelphians were also formed by someone who left the churches of Christ at that time.

Comment: You're right. I deliberately omitted the Campbellite Churches of Christ, the Nazarenes, and the Pentacostals because the OP specified "late 17th and 18th centuries".

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot that 18th century = 1700s. My bad.